# Using environment parameters in profile file Tibco BW6

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

In BW6 profile files(.substvar) we need to use substitution parameter which will be replaced by CI-CD platform just before deploy to any environment,

for example if we have three environment : dev, test, production, for those environments we have a sftp access, will have three profile files for each environment, developper will need to put values like this in profiles so the CI-CD platform replace them as needed for each environment :

[image]

My problem is with non string property, for example integer or password, how to deal with them because for example can't use #port# in an integer field using business studio, when we open as xml it works normally but in business studio can't set it.

Any best practice to deal with this ?

Comment: are you trying to enter a text (#PORT) in the numeric field, then it would not work like you said. Why do you want any label for it? Cant you keep it blank? The CICD should replace it based on the name of th GV. The name of the global variable parameter itself should be enough, dont you think?

Comment: Hi thanks for replay, the name of the GV contain three path of folders which can be different from one module to another, that's way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the value, you should see a "config" icon. Click on Container Configuration:
[image]

Once you click on it, the field will convert to "String" and you can enter the name of the variable:
[image: After the change]